# How to add "Advanced Search with adobe acrobat" command to right click of context menu?

Tags: command-line, pdf, search, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

Please How to add "Advanced Search with adobe acrobat" command to right click of context menu? for current folder because selecting the target folder inside the adobe acrobat from (Edit ----> Advanced Search) is annoying.
I want a command like "Search with SeekFast..." software which its code :

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Search with SeekFast...]
@="Search with SeekFast..."
"Icon"="C:\Program Files\SeekFast\\SeekFast.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Search with SeekFast...\command]
@=""C:\Program Files\SeekFast\\SeekFast.exe" "%V""

In conclusion, Is there any code like "Search with SeekFast"command
I replaced SeekFast path with adobe acrobat path in the code above but it does not work

Thanks

Comment: Well documented on the web, e.g. https://www.howtogeek.com/107965/how-to-add-any-application-shortcut-to-windows-explorers-context-menu/

Comment: Thanks, I know that but I want run the adobe acrobat with special parameter which is advanced search command